# Generate reports that query data from MS SQL database on Linux/CentOS?

Tags: sql-server, linux, mono, centos, fastreport

I'm trying FastReport.Mono on Linux (CentOS 7) to see if I can make an app to generate reports. Example Mono app seems to work fine with PDF and JPG export from custom dataset.

Now I need to query data from MS SQL database. I have a sample report that works well under Windows, but fails on Linux:

```
private static void ReportExportJPG()
{
  Report report = new Report();
  report.Load(@"sql-report.frx");
  report.Prepare(); // <<<--- Error here
  ...
}
```

Error message is:

> Cant find object MsSqlDataConnection

[Feature table](https://www.fast-report.com/en/fast-report-comparison/) says that MS SQL connectivity (nor ODBC, nor many others) is not available in FastReport.Mono. Does this mean it's entirely missing or I should use other ways and provide ready-made connection to FastReport somehow? If so - How?

*P.S. Running Windows report generator with MS SQL connection under Wine works well, so I assume connecting to MS SQL from CentOS is somehow viable.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following to my project source:

```
using FastReport.Data;
using FastReport.Utils;

...

RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(MsSqlDataConnection));
```